# print a string if no null value is found

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, keyerror

I find the first non value of a column using this and it works correctly

```
first_non = df['kst'].loc[df['kst'].first_valid_index()]
print(first_non)
```

This works when there is a non null value present in the column. However, if there's no non-null value present in that column, it throws an error `KeyError: None.`

How can I use this in an if else statement? So if there's a non null value present, I want to print it. If not, I want to print something else:

```
df = pd.read_excel('./test2.xlsx')
if (df['kst'].loc[df['kst'].first_valid_index()]):
    print (df['kst'].loc[df['kst'].first_valid_index()])
else:
    print('d')
```

Currently, this throws an error:

```
-->if (df['kst'].loc[df['kst'].first_valid_index()]):
...
KeyError: None
```

Comment: Can you just catch KeyError?

Comment: `if df['kst'].first_valid_index() is None:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this as an alternative.

```
df = pd.read_excel('./test2.xlsx')
try:
    print (df['kst'].loc[df['kst'].first_valid_index()])
except:
    print('No value is found')
```

Answer (score 1):

Standard way would be `try/catch` as Kenny commented:

```
try:
   print(df['kst'].loc[df['kst'].first_valid_index()])
except:
   print("no nan values")
```

If you insist on `if/else`, check the valid index first:

```
valid_idx = df['kst'].first_valid_index()
print(df.loc[valid_idx, 'kst'] if valid_idx is not None else "no nan values")
```